# Vue Dynamic Attribute

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Svg and would like to make some parts of the viewbox attribute dynamic.

```
svg :viewBox="0 0 {{x}} {{y}}" :width="x" :height="y">

</svg>
```

What is the right syntax to implement this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use interpolation, you will need a computed:

```
computed:{
  viewbox(){
    return "0 0 " + this.x + " " + this.y;
  }
}
```

Then in your markup:

```
<svg :viewBox="viewbox" :width="x" :height="y"></svg>
```

Comment: You seem to be pretty luke warm about computeds, but that's standard in `Vue` and every other MVVM framework. You can of course write it in line, but that's just nasty: `:viewBox="'0 0 '+ x + '  ' y"`

Comment: Not sure what has changed since, but the interpolation or how the value is generated doesn't seem to be what's causing the camelCase attribute to be lowercased: https://codepen.io/perpetual-education/pen/ExdLWEJ

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution does not work appropriately due to how svg handles `viewBox`.

You need to bind it as follows:
`<svg :view-box.camel="viewbox" :width="x" :height="y"></svg>`

With the other answer Vue converts the camel case of viewBox to all lowercase and the component does not render correctly. This will keep the correct camel case on viewBox

Comment: Ah ha! .came helper!!! :)   https://codepen.io/perpetual-education/pen/BaqxWYZ